# How to solve $z^9-(\overline z)^9=9|z|^4$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

We solved this as follows in class:
$$
z^9 -\overline{z^9}=2i\cdot Im(z^9) \Rightarrow 2i\cdot Im(z^9)=9|z|^4 \Rightarrow 9|z|^4=0 \Rightarrow z=0
$$

My question is why do we conclude that $9|z|^4=0$ because $2i\cdot Im(z^9)=9|z|^4$?

Why couldn't it be maybe that:
$$
|z|^4=\frac{2i\cdot Im(z^9)}{9} \Rightarrow |z|=\left(\frac{2i\cdot Im(z^9)}{9} \right)^{1 \over 4}
$$

Answer (score 6):

$z^9-\overline{z^9}$ is purely imaginary and $9|z|^4$ is real.

So if they are equal, both are $0$ -- that's the only point that is *both* on the real and the imaginary axis.

If $9|z|^4=0$ then $|z|=0$, which means that $z=0$.